# OpenCV Gives an error when using the imgproc functions

Tags: c++, opencv

when I compile and run this code, I get an error. It compiles, but when I try to run it, it gives the following error:

The application has requested the Runtime to terminate in an unusual way.

This is the code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <string>

int main() {
    cv::VideoCapture c(0);
    double rate = 10;
    bool stop(false);
    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::namedWindow("Hi!");
    int delay = 1000/rate;
    cv::Mat corners;
    while(!stop){
        if(!c.read(frame))
            break;
        cv::cornerHarris(frame,corners,3,3,0.1);
        cv::imshow("Hi!",corners);
        if(cv::waitKey(delay)>=0)
            stop = true;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

BTW, I get the same error when using the Canny edge detector.

Answer (score 0):

Your `corners` matrix is declared as a variable, but there is no memory allocated to it. The same with your `frame` variable. First you have to create a matrix big enough for the image to fit into it.

I suggest you first take a look at `cvCreateImage` so you can learn how basic images are created and handled, before you start working with video streams.

Comment: Hey, the code may be wrong, but the problem is not the allocated mem. The C++ functions allocate memory when needed, so it's ok to call them with an empty output matrix - it will be automatically created.

Comment: Hm, yes, they are not pointers. Don't the functions like cvCanny and even imshow require pointers to the cv structures Mat and iplImage?

Comment: C++ interface is very different from the C one in this case. They expect a smart pointer (not a simple pointer) which they can allocate, if needed, with the desired output. Like `if(dst.empty) || dst.size() != CORRECT_SIZE || .. different_type ) {dst.deallocate(); dst.allocate(CORRECT_SIZE_AND_TYPE)}`

Comment: how do you allocate the memory? (I got this out of a book and it doesn't say anything in there)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the capture is ready, and the image is ok:

```
if(!cap.IsOpened())
   break;

if(!c.read(frame))
        break;

if(frame.empty())
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the image to grayscale before you use the corner detector:

```
cv::Mat frameGray;
cv::cvtColor(frame, frameGray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
```